# How to get the server URL using a cron scheduled thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, server

I have a thread running using `@Scheduled` in a Java web app, which needs the current URL of the server on which it is running:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * 1/1 * *")
public void processTask() {
   // 1) Get the server URL.
   // 2) Do some other work.
}
```

Is it possible to do this without getting the URL from the properties file (or other files)?

Comment: what do you mean server url ?

Comment: please post what you have tried.

Comment: A web application knows its context, but that is only a portion of the URL.  The scheme (http/https), and authority (hostname:port) are not known.  A property is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Secondo : this thread code will be running on multiple servers, and sending out emails, in which I need the link pointing to the server from which the mail is send.

Comment: Another reason to prefer the property file - the web server and application server may be on different machines.  The application server (i.e. your application) cannot possibly know this unless you provide that information to it somehow.

Comment: You want the server hostname or one of the IPs or the URL that this application is accessible to including the port?

Comment: @Khanna111GauravKhanna , ya i need the hostname(ip) and port.

Comment: Am not even sure it is possible. Its good if I can get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to work around this issue of attempting to get the hostname however to get the port name is something I am not sure of (without the property file approach):

1. Use the `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` but this might return the loopback.
2. Iterate through the network interfaces as in `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` but this would return all the network interfaces.
3. Since this is a webapp, you could get the hostname from `servletrequest.getServerName` and store that in a Singleton or any helper class to be used in your cron job. So you store it once for use later.
4. Get the hostname from the OS. I would demonstrate this approach. It is rough code but it would suffice to demonstrate.

   > String hostname = new BufferedReader 
   >          (new InputStreamReader 
   >          (   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hostname").getInputStream())).readLine();
   >       System.out.println("Hostname: " +  hostname);

Now create a socket to that host.

```
Socket socket = new Socket (hostname, [some well known port that is always up as in port 22 in linux]);
InetSocketAddress inetSock = (InetSocketAddress) socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
System.out.println ("Socket address: " + inetSock.getAddress().getHostAddress() );
```

On my mac prints:

```
Hostname: khannas-macbook-pro.local
Socket address: 192.xxx.xx.xx
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The host name is working but i had some socket Exception, 
Socket socket = new Socket (hostname, 22);// tried 80 and 8080 too.